# Running Pdfclown on the web

Tags: pdfclown

Does anyone know the command or the way to run pdfclown on java servlet? There's pdfclown.samples.web folder included in the library but the readme says nothing about how to run the server.

Comment: What exactly keeps you from using it as is? What kind of special servlet support do you hope for?

Comment: I was hoping to integrate it with solr so that when user searches for a pdf file, it will generate a new pdf with the keyword highlighted inside the file. I was looking into tomcat as servlet but I am open to suggestions.

Comment: I have no first-hand experience with solr, and whenever I needed a servlet to return a PDF, I simply programmed that servlet to create that PDF (in more or less the same manner as in a desktop application) and then to return it as response, not using any fancy adapters provided by a PDF library.

Comment: Is there a tutorial anywhere on how to do such a thing?

Comment: You might want to look at the iText sample [PdfServlet](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=173) for inspiration. Simply replace the iText pdf Generation code by PDFClown code.

Comment: @mkl pdfclown.samples.web project actually contains an HttpServlet sample (HelloWorld).

Comment: @Stefano Ah, good to know. As mentioned, though, I'd do it my way anyways. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to *setup a local Tomcat server and plug it to pdfclown.samples.web within eclipse* (please, see among the countless trillions of tutorials available on the Web ;-) ).

BTW, you are right that the README doesn't mention the webserver setup: I'll remedy in the next release.